# forward finds MyJsp.jsp but url-> The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

MyServlet can forward to MyJsp.jsp with the following line

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/MyJsp.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

If I enter either of the urls '...mytomcat:[myportno]/WEB-INF/MyJsp.jsp' or '...mytomcat:[myportno]/MyJsp.jsp' tomcat reports 'The requested resource is not available.' (the prefix mytomcat:[myportno] is correct - it works for other pages).

Any advice or explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is *by design*.

For security reasons, tomcat (nor any other servlet or Java EE container) should **not** allow responding to a direct request for a file under `/WEB-INF`, where you find the directories `classes` and `libs`. It is common use to also put under `/WEB-INF` the jsp files that are accessible only through forward from another servlet.